# Passing attribute from custom form to a Devise Sign Up form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I would like to put an email form on the index page to collect the email of the visitor, and once submit, direct him/her to the Devise-generated user sign up page. My form has only one fields and looks like:

```
<%= form_tag(:action => 'enrolling') do %>
<%= text_field_tag "email" %>
<%= submit_tag %>
<% end %>
```

In the controller, the enrolling method looks like:

```
  def enrolling
    @email_for_enrolling = params[:email]
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to new_registration_path( {:user => {:email => @email_for_enrolling}})}
    end
```

When i try the form, the action is called (normal), but i get the error message:

```
Could not find a valid mapping for {:user=>{:email=>"####@#####.com"}}
```

I would like to load the new page in the registration view folder, and pre-populate the email for the user. What is the right approach please?

Answer (score 0):

It was actually quite simple:

```
format.html { redirect_to new_user_registration_path(email: @email_for_enrolling)}
```